# feature importance x ticks

Tags: python, charts

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 20)

x = hrdf.drop(['Attrition_Yes'], axis = 1)
y = hrdf['Attrition_Yes']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 20)

forest.fit(x_train, y_train)

importance = forest.feature_importances_

for i,v in enumerate(importance):
print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 20))
plt.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
plt.xlabel("Feature")
plt.ylabel('Importance')
plt.show()
```

using matplotlib, i created a feature importance bar chart. I need the name of the feature (column name) under each bar. I have tried xticks etc but can't figure it out. Picture of chart included.

[image]

Comment: Did you check out the documentation?  They have examples of plotting these.  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html

Comment: @Chris I did, but the bars in the documentation are labeled as feature 0, feature 1, etc. I am looking for them to state the column name.